# Silverlight service reference deployment

Tags: silverlight, iis, silverlight-3.0, service

Im having issues deploying a silverlight 3 application for the first time.

The issue is with a service reference, the Authentication one. This all works fine locally inside of VS 2008.

I cannot add new service and discover the hosted one. Eg the localpath is

```
http://localhost:9626/Services/AuthenticationService.svc
```

But if i try to discover in VS with

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Services/AuthenticationService.svc
```

I get:

> The document at the url http://www.mydomain.com/Services/AuthenticationService.svc was not recognized as a known document type.
>   The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.'.
>   - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'.
>     - Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.'.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://www.mydomain.com/Services/AuthenticationService.svc'.
>   The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
>   The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

So, i first enabled directory browsing and couldnt browse to the .svc file. So I added .svc mime type to iis and i can now navigate to it fine, and it shows the correct declaration

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" %>
```

So im at a bit of a loss at where to go from here. Im assuming once i can get the service running in VS pointing to my hosted site i could build and upload and all would be fine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

--edit

Here are the entries in the web.config, they are a bit of a mess at the moment, and i do have other services bar the Auth one.

[Link to web.config section here, having issues posting it all](http://codepaste.net/g3brbd)

Thanks again

--edit two

Ive now followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189436/wcf-errors-using-wcftestclient-to-test-a-simple-wcf-web-service) and now I have:
[this error](http://codepaste.net/9nms9o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, its fixed itself and im not entirely sure what i have done.

Maybe that command needed time for the app pool to recycle? I didnt do anything else on the server since then.